# I have CORS error even if I enable it on nest server

Tags: reactjs, axios, cors, nestjs

Hey I think the problem in my code is on the frontend react cod because if I use Postmap my api on nest works correct.

What I have to do: I'm checking on the backend if the input phare is correct. If yes it will answers to the post request sending an object contained urls of images than I will render.

In my console log when I try to post the request I have the attached image error:

[image: CORS error]

This is my function that handle the request:

```
    const getImages = async (secret) => {
      try {
          const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/secret', {secret});
          return response.data;
      } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
      }
  }

    const handleSecret = async (e) => {
      secret = phrase;
      console.log(secret)
      if (e.key === "Enter" || e.type === "click") {
          const images = await getImages(secret);
          if (images) {
            //render image if true
              setSecret(true);
          } else {
              window.alert("Incorrect phrase");
              setSecret(false);
          }
      }
  }
```

I need community help!

I have already enable cors on nest backend:

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  await app.listen(5000);
  app.enableCors();
}
bootstrap();
```

Comment: please use blockquote for errors and code not images

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable cors before using `app.listen()`. Think of regular express middleware, anything after `app.listen()` doesn't get bound to the server, it's the same thing here